# cfdiv bind and jquery function calls

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a script (`TheForm.cfm`) that I am binding to another via a `cfdiv`. What I want is to fire off relevant jQuery functions in `SubJScript.js`. For some reason, any jQuery calls from the bind (`FormSections.cfm`) are not working.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm doing wrong or not seeing. I can sure use an extra set of eyes. Thank you in advance.

Here is the relevant code:

**TheForm.cfm**

```
<DIV id="TheBigBox">
  <DIV id="SectionBody">
    <span class="SectionHeader">This is the Name of the File</span>
    <div id="tFormSec1" class="ThisFormSection_cls">
      <cfdiv id="FormSec1" class="FormSection_cls" bind="url:FormSections.cfm?ATTRIBUTES.SecNo=1" style="float:inherit" bindOnLoad="true"/>
    </div>
</DIV>
```

**FormSections.cfm**

```
<table id="ProjectTypes_tbl">
   <tr>
      <td><cfinput name="pTypeRow1" id="XXX" type="checkbox" value="New">&nbsp;New</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**SubJScript.js**

```
$a=jQuery.noConflict();

$a(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#XXX').on("click", function() {
      alert('Show this Msg');
   });
});
```

Comment: Have you included a `cfajaximport` tag on the page with the `cfdiv` (TheForm.cfm)?  See the [docs for cfdiv and the bind attribute](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a07.html).

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes, it is already included, good suggestion though.

Comment: Where are you including the `SubJScript.js` file?

Comment: Do yourself a favor...don't use CFDIV - or any of the CF user interface functionality. Use jQuery - or any other JS lib - for making and handling you AJAX requests. The UI stuff in CF is less than optimal and really offers no advantage over jQuery, etc.

Comment: @Miguel-F in the same folder where all the .cfm files are.

Comment: @ScottStroz valid point, thanks. I'll take that into consideration.

Comment: @MadushM what I meant was where in your code are you including the `SubJScript.js` file?  It is not shown in your examples.

Comment: @Miguel-F my bad, in the template `<head>` as `<script type="text/javascript" src="../ServerPages/Applications/FCOI/PRO/SubJScript.js"></script>`

Comment: @MadushM which template?